# How to start apache tomcat service in windows 7 using browser?

Tags: tomcat

I have installed Apache Tomcat 7 on Windows 7. I want to restart tomcat using web browser.
*How it's possible ?*

Comment: I don't think you can restart it from the browser. You can stop/start existing application.

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat 7 there is no built in way to restart Tomcat from the browser.

I have alternatives for you.

1). Write and deploy a servlet that will execute a windows script (.bat file). In that script: i) Place a 30 second pause at the start then call your \apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin shutdown script ii) a loop that looks for the absence of the main tomcat process in the os iii) call your \apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin startup script.

2). Use a lightweight remote such as TightVNC to remotely connect to your windows installation and manually bounce tomcat.

3). Write a script that wakes up every few minutes and checks an external FTP service for the presence of a file with a certain name, if it exists bounce tomcat (you would put the file out on ftp to signal you want tomcat to bounce).

4) As demostene mentioned. If its just a web app on tomcat you want to restart you can use tomcats web application manager to [stop] and then [reload] any of the deployed webapps. The application manager is accessible via a link on the "Congratulations you have installed tomcat" page or the equivalent of http://localhost:8080/manager  remotely you would replace localhost with the ipaddress or domain name you are using.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for reply. Is it possible to use Tomcat Virtual Host Manager to restart tomcat service for particular application?

Comment: Hi Anup, very sorry for the late reply. To answer your question: This is not the purpose/functionality of the Virtual Host Manager. As I mentioned in 4) above. It is super easy to restart a particular webapp from the Web Application Manager(WAM). As mentioned in 4) above, the WAM is easy to access and available with the same user and password and from the same menu as the Virtual Host Manager.